# Virtualbox, Win 7 host and Win 7 guest share folder

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have Windows 7 as host and I am running VirtualBox with Windows 7 as guest. I have created share folder on my host but I do not know how to access it from guest. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about shared folders in VirtualBox [here](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/shared-folders-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7/).

> Fortunately a bit of searching yielded
>   this article, which describes the
>   problem nicely.  It turns out that
>   there is a magic word you have to
>   know, and that is the share name for
>   the host OS:
>
> ```
> \\vboxsrv
> ```

Answer (score 2):

*(I ran into trouble too, the other answers did not help me, but I eventually found the solution which I am sharing with you)*

In a nutshell it is:

- On Host machine, share a folder under the name "share".
- On guest machine, map it using "net use x:\vboxsrv\share"

More details on [Shared Folders in VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)

**But, if it still fails, it is probably because Guest Additions are not installed.**

On Guest machine, click in the menu: Devices > Install Guest Additions...

Navigate to the virtual CD-ROM just created, and install VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Hugues, turned out indeed I hadn't set up the Guest Additions. After this it automatically set it up like Randolph mentioned